# Assign static member to a const

Tags: c#

Suppose you have a class with shared members to make a reference to known values like this

```
public class Semaphore()
{
    public static int Red = 0;
    public static int Yellow = 1;
    public static int Green = 2;
}
```

In VB.Net you can assign these static (shared) values to a const like this:

```
Public Class Transit
    Private Const Red as Integer = Semaphore.Red
End Class
```

But in C# this isn't possible.  There is a reason for this?  Some workaround?

UPDATE

Indeed, VB.NET behaves in the same manner that C#.  At least in VS 2012.  The only difference is that in C# the shared member isn't even available in intellisense.

Comment: Not convinced it is possible in VB...

Comment: Why not use an `enum`...? It would be more typesafe and you can even use it as a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `const` you can use `readonly` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

> The readonly keyword differs from the const keyword. A const field can
>   only be initialized at the declaration of the field. A readonly field
>   can be initialized either at the declaration or in a constructor.
>   Therefore, readonly fields can have different values depending on the
>   constructor used. Also, although a const field is a compile-time
>   constant, the readonly field can be used for run-time constants, as in
>   this line: public static readonly uint l1 = (uint)DateTime.Now.Ticks;

C# workaround example:

```
public class Semaphore
{
    public static int Red = 0;
    public static int Yellow = 1;
    public static int Green = 2;
}

class Transit
{
    readonly int Red = Semaphore.Red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it your intent that `Semaphore.Red` can be changed:

```
Semaphore.Red = 5;
```

If not, use constants there:

```
public class Semaphore
{
    public const int Red = 0;
    public const int Yellow = 1;
    public const int Green = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Indeed, VB.NET behaves in the same manner that C#. At least in VS 2012. The only difference is that in C# the shared member isn't even available in intellisense.

That's because in VB all `Public` and `Friend` `Module` members can be called without specifying the `Module` name:

Consider following `Module`:

```
Namespace TestNamespace

    Module TestModule

        Public ReadOnly Property TestPropertyFromModule As String
            Get
                Return "My Test Property Value"
            End Get
        End Property

    End Module

End Namespace
```

As long as you have `Imports TestNamespace` at the top of your file, you can call `TestPropertyFromModule` without specifying `TestModule` name:

```
Imports TestNamespace

Public Class TestClass

    Public Sub New()
        Dim test = TestPropertyFromModule
    End Sub

End Class
```

In C# it's not possible. You have to use `class` name and write `TestModule.TestPropertyFromModule`. That's why intellisense on VB.NET shows different set of available methods/property/etc then in C#.